# Filter and Ultrafilter questions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove an ultrafilter on a finite set must be principle.

I'm not really too sure how to go about this:

Let I be a finite set and let U be an ultrafilter on I.

That's the extent of my working so far... I know it's not much but can anyone give a nudge in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $U$ isn't principal.  Then for each $i\in I$, $I\setminus\{i\}$ must be in $U$.  Can you get a contradiction from this?

Comment: Eric, Is the contradiction that I\{i} is finite. Therefore U cannot be non-principle?